# How to create an FTP user with access to ALL websites, current and future?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ftp

I have a new Hostinger VPS and I'm migrating all my websites over from Bluehost. Setting up an FTP user (**I am running ProFTPD**) through CloudPanel is quick and easy, but it seems to be only doable on a site-specific basis. For example, if I have [www.whatever.com](http://www.whatever.com), I can create an FTP account that can get to ONLY that website's files and no others. This is bad for me because I have about 20 websites and I want to have a single global-admin FTP account that can get to all of them. This is what I currently have at Bluehost. So when I login from FileZilla, I want to be able to navigate in and out of all my websites and have full access to everything.

I do not want to have to have a different user account for every one of my websites.

I tried following [these steps](https://www.bennetrichter.de/en/tutorials/ftp-server-linux/) exactly using an `ftpadmin` user I created and set the home directory to `/home` (since that is where CloudPanel installs all new websites). No success, always the same error.

How can I set this up through the bash terminal? (I already created a user account and [I thought] gave him access to the `/home` directory, under which I think all websites get created, through `htdocs`.) But my FTP connection doesn't work for that account and I'm pretty sure I did something wrong.

Comment: Which ftp Daemon are you using? What configuration are you using for that?

Comment: Not sure how your server is set up, but being a member of `www-data` should in theory be enough, no?

Comment: muru: I am running `ProFTPD`. Apologies for not mentioning that. I have updated my original post to state it. Panki: Could you clarify what you're saying about `www-data`, I am a linux noob.

Comment: You need to mention people with an `@` for them to get notified. `www-data` is the default user and group that runs the webserver. Usually, almost everything in `/var/www` belongs to `www-data` (the group has permissions to at least read).

Comment: Also, reading the question again - putting websites under `/home` is wrong in my opinion. For more info on the folders and what they are meant for, read `man file-hierarchy`

Comment: I agree that it's odd for websites to be placed under `/home`, but that's how Hostinger does it, and I dare not mess with that.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, WebPanels (like cPanel and WHM) usually create an user for each account, and organize the account's files under /home/user, so probably CloudPanel also works this way. That said, I believe you could achieve what you want using Linux ACLs, combined with ProFTPD mod_facl module (http://www.proftpd.org/docs/modules/mod_facl.html). I never used it, but it is the way I would try if I ever needed something like that.

Comment: I was hoping for something a bit more specific, but thanks for posting.